# "No tests found" error in a module that has no tests

Tags: android, gradle, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I got a "No tests found" error for a specific module that has no instrumented tests (only JUnit tests) when running `gradlew connectedAndroidTest` in the pipeline. It's a bad thing because the app has other modules that have instrumented tests that don't run because the Gradle task fails.

[image: Task :actions:connectedDebugAndroidTest Starting 0 tests on android_emulator(AVD) - 8.1.0 com.android.build.gradle.internal.testing.ConnectedDevice > No tests found.android_emulator(AVD) - 8.1.0 FAILED No tests found. This usually means that your test classes are not in the form that your test runner expects (e.g. don't inherit from TestCase or lack @Test annotations). Task :actions:connectedDebugAndroidTest FAILED]

I've tried removing `androidTest` dependencies and `testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"` but the problem is still happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting `androidTest` directory solved the problem (the folder had no classes but had a .gitkeep file).

Apparently, it fails when the folder exists but has no tests in it.